# docusign 401 connecting from server, works in postman

Tags: rest, http, docusignapi

I am just trying to authenticate from NetSuite to docusign.  I have my demo account, and am able to send requests successfully using the legacy authentication from postman.

However, when I try the same code in a server side situation, i get the INVALID_TOKEN_FORMAT error.

I've only built 3 or 4 apis so would really appreciate what I might be missing that's causing this 401 error.

NetSuite code (js syntax):

> headers = {
>                     'Accept':'application/json',
>                     'Content-Type':'application/json',
>                     'X-DocuSign-Authentication':{'Username':'abcusername','Password':'password123','IntegratorKey':'xyz123'}
>                 };
>   res = nlapiRequestURL('https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information', '', headers, 'GET');

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved! The authentication object needed to be in xml. Confused bc of the content type and the documentation shows JSON